# Perform subtract on the values from two select statement in grafana

Tags: google-bigquery, grafana

I have an grafana query that performs a simple count of total, success and failures and I would like to perform a simple arithmetic operation like below

`warnings=total-(success+failures)'`

but unfortunately I am unable to get that done through the `SUM`, can someone help me to fix it.

Below is my query which I have tried

```
SELECT(SELECT count(*) FROM student ) AS TOTAL,
(SELECT count(*) FROM student where marks > 60) AS Success,
(SELECT count(*) FROM student where marks < 35) AS Failed,
SUM(TOTAL-Success-Failed) AS Moderate
```

and

```
SELECT(SELECT count(*) FROM student ) AS TOTAL,
(SELECT count(*) FROM student where marks > 60) AS Success,
(SELECT count(*) FROM student where marks < 35) AS Failed,
SELECT(TOTAL-Success-Failed) AS Moderate
```

can someone help me to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to use a subquery

```sql
SELECT (TOTAL-Success-Failed) AS Moderate
  FROM (
    SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM student ) AS TOTAL,
           (SELECT count(*) FROM student where marks > 60) AS Success,
           (SELECT count(*) FROM student where marks < 35) AS Failed
  )
```

and if above query works as you expect, you can make your query more simple like below.

```sql
SELECT count(*) - countif(marks > 60) - countif(marks < 35) AS Moderate
  FROM student
```